# In Rest CRUD with OneToOne,when i am inserting data with form it working fine.But the problem comes with updating and deleting

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc, jpa

--> when i am Updating it was not saving the entered details insted it was saving null. when deleting it throws error.

[DataBase : restonetoone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgc8w.png)

```
application.properties
/*****************************/

crm.rest.url=http://localhost:8080/restonetoone/api/details
```

```
-->when i use to update it was taking null value insted of inserted data.

 Details [id=25, city=null, mobileno=0, student=Student [id=25, name=null, clas=0]]
```

```
 ->when i was deleting it throws this error.

    Mar 06, 2021 4:09:53 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
    WARNING: No mapping for GET /restclient/student/delete
```

the Details.java class Onetoone with student.java class

```
Details.java
/******************/
package com.rest.entity;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="details")
public class Details {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    private String city;
    
    private long mobileno;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="student_id")
    private Student student;
    
    public Details(){
        
    }


    public Details(int id, String city, long mobileno, Student student) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.city = city;
        this.mobileno = mobileno;
        this.student = student;
    }



    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public long getMobileno() {
        return mobileno;
    }

    public void setMobileno(long mobileno) {
        this.mobileno = mobileno;
    }

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Details [id=" + id + ", city=" + city + ", mobileno=" + mobileno + ", student=" + student + "]";
    }
    
}
```

student.java class

```
Student.java
/******************/
package com.rest.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    private String name;
    
    private int clas;
    
    public Student() {
        
    }


    public Student(int id, String name, int clas) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.clas = clas;
    }



    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getClas() {
        return clas;
    }

    public void setClas(int clas) {
        this.clas = clas;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", clas=" + clas + "]";
    }
    
    
}
```

DetailsServImpl.java class(service layers)

```
DetailsServImpl.java
/******************/
package com.rest.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.rest.entity.Details;
@Service
public class DetailsServImpl implements DetailsServ {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private String crmRestUrl;
        
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
    
    @Autowired
    public DetailsServImpl(RestTemplate theRestTemplate, 
            @Value("${crm.rest.url}") String theUrl) {
        restTemplate = theRestTemplate;
        crmRestUrl = theUrl;
                
        logger.info("Loaded property:  crm.rest.url=" + crmRestUrl);
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public List<Details> getDetails() {
        logger.info("in getDetails(): Calling REST API " + crmRestUrl);

        // make REST call
        ResponseEntity<List<Details>> responseEntity = 
                                            restTemplate.exchange(crmRestUrl, HttpMethod.GET, null, 
                                                                  new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Details>>() {});

        // get the list of customers from response
        List<Details> theDetails = responseEntity.getBody();

        logger.info("in getDetails(): details" + theDetails);
        return theDetails;
    }

    @Override
    public Details getDetails(int theId) {
        logger.info("in getDetails(): Calling REST API " + crmRestUrl);

        // make REST call
        Details theDetails = 
                restTemplate.getForObject(crmRestUrl + "/" + theId, 
                                          Details.class);

        logger.info("in saveDetails(): theDetails=" + theDetails);
        
        return theDetails;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveDetails(Details theDetails) {
logger.info("in saveSt(): Cudentalling REST API " + crmRestUrl);
        
        int detailsId = theDetails.getId();

        // make REST call
        if (detailsId == 0) {
            // add employee
            restTemplate.postForEntity(crmRestUrl, theDetails, String.class);           
        
        } else {
            // update employee
            restTemplate.put(crmRestUrl, theDetails);
        }

        logger.info("in saveDetails(): success");

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteDetails(int theId) {
        logger.info("in deleteDetails(): Calling REST API " + crmRestUrl);

        // make REST call
        restTemplate.delete(crmRestUrl + "/" + theId);

        logger.info("in deleteDetails(): deleted Details theId=" + theId);

    }

}
```

StudentServImpl.java class

```
StudentServImpl.java
/******************/
package com.rest.service;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.rest.entity.Details;
import com.rest.entity.Student;
@Service
public class StudentServImpl implements StudentServ {
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private String crmRestUrl;
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
    @Autowired
    public StudentServImpl(RestTemplate theRestTemplate,@Value("${crm.rest.url}") String theUrl){
        restTemplate = theRestTemplate;
        crmRestUrl = theUrl;
        logger.info("Loaded property:  crm.rest.url=" + crmRestUrl);
    }
    @Override
    public List<Student> getStudent() {
        logger.info("in getCustomers(): Calling REST API " + crmRestUrl);

        // make REST call
        ResponseEntity<List<Student>> responseEntity = 
                                            restTemplate.exchange(crmRestUrl, HttpMethod.GET, null, 
                                                                  new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Student>>() {});

        // get the list of customers from response
        List<Student> theStudent = responseEntity.getBody();
        logger.info("in getCustomers(): customers" + theStudent);
        return theStudent;
    }
    @Override
    public void saveStudent(Student theStudent) {
logger.info("in saveSt(): Cudentalling REST API " + crmRestUrl);    

        
        int studentId = theStudent.getId();
        // make REST call
        if (studentId == 0) {
            // add employee
            restTemplate.postForEntity(crmRestUrl, theStudent, String.class);           
        
        } else {
            // update employee
            restTemplate.put(crmRestUrl, theStudent);
        }
        logger.info("in saveStudent(): success");       
    }
    @Override
    public Student getStudent(int theId) {
        logger.info("in getCustomer(): Calling REST API " + crmRestUrl);
        // make REST call
        Student theStudent = 
                restTemplate.getForObject(crmRestUrl + "/" + theId, 
                                          Student.class);
        logger.info("in saveCustomer(): theCustomer=" + theStudent);
        return theStudent;
    }
    @Override
    public void deleteStudent(int theId) {
        logger.info("in deleteStudent(): Calling REST API " + crmRestUrl);
        // make REST call
        restTemplate.delete(crmRestUrl + "/" + theId);
        logger.info("in deleteStudent(): deleted Student theId=" + theId);
    }
}
```

Now the controller class(here i am using single controller for multiple entites).

```
ClientController.java
/******************/
package com.rest.controller;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.rest.entity.Details;
import com.rest.entity.Student;
import com.rest.service.DetailsServ;
import com.rest.service.StudentServ;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/cont")
public class ClientController {

    @Autowired
    private DetailsServ detailsServ;
    
    @Autowired
    private StudentServ studentServ;
    
    @GetMapping("/showForm")
    public String showForm(Model theModel){
        Details theDetails = new Details(); 
        Student theStudent = new Student();
        theDetails.setStudent(theStudent);
        theModel.addAttribute("for",theDetails);
        return "the-for";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/saveForm")
    private String saveForm(@ModelAttribute("for") Details theDetails) {
        detailsServ.saveDetails(theDetails);
        return "redirect:/cont/list";
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String showList(Model theModel) {
        List<Details> theDetails = detailsServ.getDetails();
        theModel.addAttribute("details", theDetails);
        return "list-table";
    }
    @GetMapping("/update")
    public String updateDetails(@RequestParam("detailsId") int theId, Model theModel) {
        Details theDetails =detailsServ.getDetails(theId);
        theModel.addAttribute("for",theDetails);
        return "the-for"; 
    }
    @GetMapping("/delete")
    public String deleteDetails(@RequestParam("detailsId") int theId) {
        
        detailsServ.deleteDetails(theId);
        return "redirect:/cont/list";
    }   
    
    
}
```

I use this form for both saving and updating.

```
the-for.jsp
/******************/
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
 <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%> 
 <%@ page import="java.sql.*"%> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Save Customer</title>

    <link type="text/css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css">

    <link type="text/css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/add-customer-style.css">
</head>

<body>
    
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <h2>Form</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="container">
        <h3>Save StudentDetails</h3>
    
        <form:form action="saveForm" modelAttribute="for" method="POST">

            <!-- need to associate this data with customer id -->
            <form:hidden path="id" />
                    
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>City name:</label></td>
                        <td><form:input path="city" /></td>
                    </tr>
                
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>mobileno:</label></td>
                        <td><form:input path="mobileno" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label>name:</label></td>
                        <td><form:input path="student.name" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>class:</label></td>
                        <td><form:input path="student.clas" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label></label></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Save" class="save" /></td>
                    </tr>

                
                </tbody>
            </table>
        
        
        </form:form>
    
        <div style="clear; both;"></div>
        
        <p>
            <a href="list">Back to List</a>
        </p>
    
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Now the table which shows the CRUD dynamically.

```
list-table.jsp
/******************/
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> 
 <%@ page import = "java.sql.*" %> 

 

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>List</title>

<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <h2 class="pt-2">Student Manager</h2>

        <!-- put new button: Add Student -->

        <input type="button" value="Add Student"
            onclick="window.location.href='showForm'; return false;"
            class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3" />

        <!--  add our html table here -->

        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">

            <thead class="table-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>city</th>
                    <th>mobileno</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>class</th>
                    <th>Action</th> 
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <!-- loop over and print our students -->
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach var="tempDetails" items="${details}">

         <!-- construct an "update" link with student id -->
                    <c:url var="updateLink" value="/cont/update"> 
                        <c:param name="detailsId" value="${tempDetails.id}" /> 
                    </c:url> 

                <!-- construct an "delete" link with student id -->
                    <c:url var="deleteLink" value="/student/delete"> 
                        <c:param name="studentId" value="${tempStudent.id}" /> 
                    </c:url> 

                    <tr>
                        <td>${tempDetails.city}</td>
                        <td>${tempDetails.mobileno}</td>
                        <td>${tempDetails.student.name}</td> 
                        <td>${tempDetails.student.clas}</td> 
                        
                        <td>
                            <!-- display the update link --> 
                            <a href="${updateLink}">Update</a> 
                                        |
                             <a href="${deleteLink}" 
                            onclick="if (!(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this student?'))) return false">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>

        </table>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

For more clearity sake i am shering the link of my project which include  Both client side and backend code files with database.
LINK( https://drive.google.com/file/d/128pvCd6bYdCNhOiG6ERRXbPRUlnhZlTp/view?usp=sharing )

Comment: Please post the code responsible for *actually* updating/deleting the entity

Comment: It    ClientController.java    which is used to controll, and      list-table.jsp      file which is used to display the CRUD for insert update and delete these are two already mentioned above.waiting for ur replay Bro.

Comment: Regarding deletion, you're constructing a link using `c:url` which reads `/student/delete`. There is no mapping for `/student/delete` in your controller, only `/cont/delete` exists